# Find $f(2015)$ in function $f$ defined below

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be the set $\mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\}$

Let a function $f:\mathbb{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{S} $ be defined as:
$$f(x^2+y^2) = y^2f(x)+x^2f(y) +x^4+y^4$$

If done so, then what would be the value of $f(2015)$?

Comment: If you have any questions about my answer below, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting $ x = y = 0 $, we get $ f(0) = 0 $.
Putting $ y = 0 $, we have $ f(x^2) = x^4 $. Putting $ z = x^2 $, we have $ f(z) = z^2 $ for all $ z \geq 0 $.
$$\therefore f(2015) = 2015^2= 4060225$$